# How to keep the Row Height constant when a table is pushed down on the sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with 2 tables.
Each table has a header that I want to be a height of 30 while all table rows are the standard 15.
When I add a row to the top table, the bottom table gets pushed down.
The header Height on the bottom table picks up the height of the new spreadsheet row.
Is there a way to make the bottom table keep its header height at 30?
Here is my code to add rows to the top table.

```
            Set tblAssemblies = Worksheets("Summary").ListObjects("Table1")
            Count = 1
            Do
                tblAssemblies.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
                Count = Count + 1
            Loop While Count <= Target.Value - tblAssembliesRows
```

This pushed the bottom table down, but not the formatting of the sheet row for the header height.
Any Ideas?

Rich

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## HeaderRowRange.RowHeight

I've noticed, and you didn't mention, that the '30-height-row moves' into the first table. This should be corrected, too.

```
Option Explicit

Sub HeaderRowRangeRowHeight()

  With Worksheets("Summary")
    .ListObjects(2).HeaderRowRange.RowHeight = 30
    .ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.RowHeight = 15
    .ListObjects(1).TotalsRowRange.RowHeight = 15
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where `Target`'s range is in reference to the header of the table in question, but you could do something like

```
rows(target.row).rowheight = 22.5
```

If your header, for example, is always three rows below the `Target`, then you would just add 3:

```
rows(target.row + 3).rowheight = 22.5
```

Comment: This may not work so easily. The top table may grow and shrink in length as the user works his task.
So for example, if the bottom table is 3 worksheet rows below the top table, and the user adds 6 rows, then the 4th row in the top table picks up the taller row from where the bottom table used to start.
I then would need to produce code to keep track of what row the bottom table starts on and if the top table grows more than 3 then change the row height. Then keep track of where the new table ends up and increase that row's height.
I was hoping the add row function could automatically do it

Comment: If you set the table to a range, you can use the range’s `rows.count` property to adjust for these changes