# Set specific height for all existing/new rows of a table

Tags: excel, vba

I have used Excel for quite some time now but only using traditional formulas. Now I am trying to create a more elaborated document for my business using VBA coding to expand my possibilities.

I have done some research and started practicing but found something that I can’t understand how to do yet.

I have a worksheet with a table on it. Since this is a fresh document it has nothing but the header and a blank row below it. What I always did when writing the information was type text in any of the columns that belong to the row immediately below the table (without actually inserting a new row myself). This creates a new row for the table where most of its format is kept, such as text size and formulas. However, I noticed that the row height doesn’t automatically change to that of the previous rows of the table, and changing it manually for each new row is very time consuming.

I would really appreciate it if anyone could share me the necessary Excel VBA code to fix this issue. I have thought of two possible approaches. The first one is a code that automatically sets all the rows of the table to a height of 20 (I want all rows to be the same size so no problem with that), supposing this would also affect new rows as I add them the way I mentioned. The second one would be a code that automatically sets every new row of the table to a size of 20. It doesn’t matter which one you choose, the easiest will be just fine. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In its most primitive form I would suggest using the `Worksheet_Change` event, then setting the `RowHeight` property of the `DataBodyRange`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53180807/9758194) is an example.

Comment: @JvdV I found that post before publishing mine but that code is way more complex than what I need. I just use a single table per worksheet. Thank you for the hint, the trigger event you mentioned is great but would it be possible to just look for changes at the table and not at the whole worksheet to speed up the process? Would something like this work?`Sub TableRowHeight()

Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .ListObjects(Table1).DataBodyRange.RowHeight = 20
  End With

End Sub`

Comment: There is as far as I know no such trigger. If you say you don't want to get complex code, then forget about the idea. You'll run into much more complex code.